# low speed on cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I use query

```
"START a=node("+str(node1)+"),
       b =node("+str(node2)+") 
MATCH p=shortestPath(a-[:cooperate*..200]-b) 
RETURN length(p)"
```

to see the path between a and b. I have many nodes, so when i run the query, sometimes it runs fast and sometimes run slowly.I use neo4j 1.9 community. Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 1):

Query time is proportional to the amount of the graph searched. Your query allows for very deep searches, up to depth 200. If a. and b. are very close, you'll not search much of the graph, and the query will return very fast. If a. and b. are separated by 200 edges, you will search a very large swathe of graph (perhaps the whole graph?), which for a large graph will be much slower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually i should use * instead of 200 because i can not define the search depth.I think maybe it is something with jvm memory

Answer (score 0):

Is the graph changing between the two queries, is it possible these two nodes end up in different places in relation to eachother between the queries? For example if you generate some random data to populate the graph?

Comment: Thanks! The graph will not change and my goal is to calculate the shortest path between many node in order to get the average path length. But it sometimes works fast while sometimes slowly. I think maybe it's something related to jvm memory...

Comment: Can you describe the hardware you have the database running on? Is it a dedicated machine, VPS, your personal laptop? What other services and processes are running?